# determine a solution using intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> Given equation $x^{100} + x^{99} + x^{98} + ... + x + 1 = 5$ I need to determine whether there exists one solution $x$ such that $x > 0$. Also, whether I have one solution $x < 0$.

First, I let $a = 0$ such that $f(a) = 1$. Let $b = 1$ such that $f(b) = 101$. Since $f(a) < 5 < f(b)$, thus, by intermediate value theorem, there exits one solution $x \in(0, 1)$. Similarly, I can conclude that there exits one solution smaller than $0$. Is my process correct?

Comment: $$\frac{x^{101}-1}{x-1}=5$$

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: you are right, but it would not be bad to premise that f is continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes since the function is continuous and, as noticed in the comments, by geometric series we have for $x\neq 1$

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{101}-1}{x-1}$$

therefore

$$f(-1)=1 \quad f(-2)>5$$

also for $x<0$ at least a solution exists in the interval $(-2,-1)$.